# Can't get updates Ubuntu 18.04 Permission denied

Tags: permissions, updates

Last year laptop screen got broken and I just replaced it (imagine the updates waiting). Upon 1st boot into linux side of dual boot win10 system, I didn't use terminal to update, but rather clicked on the taskbar icon and chose update. It started and I kept seeing error messages popping up so today I tried using terminal and here is what I got:

```
$ apt-get update --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I really need to get all updated. How do I fix permission denied?

Comment: You need granted rights. `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks. That did it and then I did sudo apt-get upgrade.